# Limit of label [category] for FastText classifier in text analytic

Tags: machine-learning, fasttext

I am wondering if there is any limit to number of label or category a text classifier can handle?

Browsing throughout many text analytic API, most do not seems to categorize more than 20.

Comment: I fixed your tags - ML is a programming language, not "machine learning".